# Change Month Numbers to Names and to Turkish (Symfony 4)

Tags: symfony, datetime

I learn Symfony 4 from scratch. I try to produce a simple page by means of which one can create a to do list with a due date.

```
<?php 


namespace App\Controller;

setlocale(LC_TIME, "tr_TR");

use App\Entity\Task;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use DateTime;


class FormControllerErdem extends Controller
{

public function new1(Request $request)
{

    $task = new Task();
    $task->setTask('Görev Yaz');
    $task->setDueDate(new DateTime('tomorrow'));

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('task', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Görev '))
        ->add('dueDate', DateType::class, array('label' => 'Son Gün','format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy','widget' => 'choice'))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Görev Oluştur'))
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

}
```

The result of the code above is :

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHCed.png)

What I want is, for example: "12 Ocak 2018". Ocak means January in Turkish. How can I manage that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the timezone on specific datetime object, like that:

```
$date = new DateTime('2018-04-11', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Istanbul'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');
```

Comment: Adding "new DateTimeZone('Europe/Istanbul'));" did the trick. Thanks.